# Очень большой update

Tags: php, mysql, sql

У меня в базе хранится список файлов. На странице надо отображать их размер. Раньше это делалось динамически (через функцию `filesize`), сейчас это стало невозможно (файлы были вынесены на отдельный файловый сервер). Надо заносить размеры в базу. Я взял с помощью sql сформировал csv из id и путей. С помощью php распарсил, получил размеры и сформировал кучу bulk update вида `update files set size = (case id when 123 then 321 end);`. По 10к when/then внутри. Записей очень много... Вообщем когда все выполнилось я посмотрел логи этих апдейтов и заметил что в некоторых случаях проапдейтилось даже больше строк чем было в блоке, а в некоторых наоборот меньше. Как такое может быть не представляю.

Вот если интересно так я получил csv (у меня две таких таблицы):

```
select concat(id, ':', path) as line
from article_files;

select concat(id, ':', path) as line
from payment_files;
```

А таким php-шным скриптом я их обработал:

```
function file_get_lines($filename, $lineBreak = "\n") {
    return explode($lineBreak, file_get_contents($filename));
}

function computeFileSizes($table) {
    $input = array_map(function($line) {
        return explode(':', $line);
    }, file_get_lines("${table}_input.txt"));

    $output = [];

    foreach ($input as list($id, $filename)) {
        $size = filesize($filename) ?: 0;
        $output[] = "when $id then $size";
    }

    $sqlParts = [];

    foreach (array_chunk($output, 10000) as $outputParts) {
        $whenParts = implode("\n", $outputParts);
        $sqlParts[] = "update $table set size = (case id\n${whenParts}\nend);";
    }

    file_put_contents("${table}_output.txt", implode("\n", $sqlParts));
}

computeFileSizes('article_files');
computeFileSizes('payment_files');
```

В итоге проапдейтилось меньше половины! С чем это может быть связано? И вообще может есть более простой способ сделать это?

Comment: Вот здесь https://stackoverflow.com/a/44931466/6848880 люди говорят, что самый быстрый способ это одиночные `update` объеденные через `multi_query` (http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.multiple-statement.php)

Comment: @YuriyProkopets ну запускал то я это все просто - скопировал содержимое выходного файла в навикат и нажал на запуск... Что касается скорости то как раз таки bulk update быстрее намного. Я в начале пытался одиночными update обойтись - ждал чуть ли не полчаса, потом мне надоело и я вырубил запрос. А вот bulk update минут за 5 управился. Но проблема не в скорости, а в потере данных.

Comment: Быстрее - отправить CSV  на сервер, а там LOAD DATA INFILE в TEMPORARY, а потом один UPDATE.

Comment: @Akina я не знаю о чем вы говорите. О_о Но у меня нет ssh доступа к серверу базы данных, только к самой базе.

Comment: Зачем SSH? Достаточно любого доступа - скажем, FTP.

Comment: @Akina нет. Полностью отсутствует любой доступ к серверу где хостится база.

Comment: *проблема не в скорости, а в потере данных.* Ну на самом деле не бывает... Запрос или выполняется - причём полностью, или приводит к ошибке - и тогда не выполняется вообще. Кстати, а что в логах, ошибки-то есть?

Comment: Для того, чтобы иметь возможность контроля и проверки, я бы предложил подготовленные данные загрузить в отдельную таблицу (без индексов это должно быть быстро), проиндексировать её для комфортного выполнения обновления, после чего собственно и выполнить обновление данных.

Comment: @Akina что я уже и сделал, но все равно спасибо! :) Проблема решена!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вообщем я переделал скрипт и сформировал `insert` во временную таблицу вместо `update` существующей. Так что вставились все записи без потерь. А потом просто проапдейтил из нее уже.